# What algorithm does FileSystemWatcher in C# use to monitor file system changes?

Tags: c#, .net, filesystemwatcher

I wish to understand how FileSystemWatcher monitors changes.

Is there a central set of Windows system API that are central conduit for creation, removal, changing of file system objects, such that each change causes the API to post a notification that FileSystemWatcher subscribes to?

Or does FileSystemWatcher simply continually polls the path specified looking for differences?

I wrote a C# routine using FileSystemWatcher to watch the entire C drive, and tested it by creating, deleting, renaming files. The response was quite immediate.

Comment: You misunderstand what "algorithm" means....

Comment: Does this question not already answer yours?: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71295028/how-does-system-io-filesystemwatcher-works-under-the-hood

Comment: "Is there a central set of Windows system API that are central conduit for creation, removal, changing of file system objects, such that each change causes the API to post a notification that FileSystemWatcher subscribes to?" - [yes, that's how it works](https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/System/services/io/system/io/FileSystemWatcher.cs).

Comment: Are you saying this opinion. that FSW continually scans,  is wrong: https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/5311384/Filesystemwatcher-on-all-drives

Comment: https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/System/services/io/system/io/FileSystemWatcher.cs#L729

Comment: No, `FileSystemWatcher` does not "continually scan" your filesystem. The comments in that CodeProject article are factually incorrect: we've linked you to the source-code of `FileSystemWatcher` and you can see it's just a wrapper over Win32's [`ReadDirectoryChangesW`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-readdirectorychangesw).